# $\text{det}(I-AB)=\text{det}(I-BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that for $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ that $\text{det}(I-AB)=\text{det}(I-BA)$.

My thought is that since $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues, I know they have they same minimal polynomial. If I can further show they have the the same characteristic polynomial, I'm done.

Is that true though? the characteristic polynomials for $A$ and $B$ respectively are $P_A(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{c_1}...(x-\lambda_j)^{c_j}$ and $P_B(x)=(x-\lambda_1)^{d_1}...(x-\lambda_j)^{d_j}$ where $\lambda_q\neq\lambda_p$, $j\leq n$ and the superscripts are the dimensions of the the generalized eigenspaces. Is it true that $c_k=d_k?$

Comment: The easiest way is probably to first show it in case one of $A$ or $B$ is invertible (conjugate by it), then use that invertible matrices form a dense subset and the determinant is continuous.

Comment: I have seen something like that recently [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842337/253273) Otherwise, the classical proof is due to [Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) (Actually, as I see now he stated it in 1851 *without a proof*, perhabs the margins of his book were too small).

Comment: @A.G. Heh, that is indeed precisely the argument I had in mind.

Comment: The fact about characteristic polynomials is true. It follows easily from the very equality you are trying to prove (just replace $A$ with $\frac{1}{\lambda}A$). That doesn't really help you though.

Comment: @DanShved But the answer of N.S. really does help, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You don't have to use eigenvalues, but is simpler with them)

Hint:  $\det(I-AB) = \det\left(\begin{array}{c c} I & 0 \\ A & I-AB \end{array}  \right)$

Comment: What does it give me?