# Eigenvalues for a spacial block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find the non-zero eigen-values of a matrix of the following form

\begin{align}
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{0}_{n_1 \times n_1} & \mathbf{0}_{n_1 \times n_2} & \mathbf{0}_{n_1 \times n_3} \\
\mathbf{A}_{n_2 \times n_1} & \mathbf{B}_{n_2 \times n_2} & \mathbf{C}_{n_2 \times n_3} \\
\mathbf{0}_{n_3 \times n_1} & \mathbf{0}_{n_3 \times n_2} & \mathbf{0}_{n_3 \times n_3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where the subscripts indicate the size of the corresponding block matrix, that is $\mathbf{A}_{n_2 \times n_1}$ is a $n_2 \times n_1$ matrix. My guess is that eigen-values of $M$ include $n_1 + n_3$ zeros and eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$. For simple examples, this intuition is correct, but I want to know whether this is correct for the block matrix $M$ described above? Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is that these matrices are not square. For square block matrices you can use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207865/the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix). So you could change the first and second "block-row" of your matrix and form square matrices. Maybe these formed square matrices have nice properties.

Comment: @P.Siehr Thanks for your suggestion. I think the question you linked actually can solve my problem. Why do we need all matrices to be square? I think we can apply determinant to block matrices and conclude my conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work over the algebraic closure of the base field.  Suppose $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.  Then,
$$\mathbf{M}-\lambda \mathbf{I}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda \mathbf{I} & \textbf{0} &\textbf{0}
\\
\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{B}-\lambda \mathbf{I}&\mathbf{C}
\\
\textbf{0}&\textbf{0}&-\lambda\mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]$$
Using a sequence of row operations, we can reduce $\mathbf{M}-\lambda \mathbf{I}$ to a form
$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda \mathbf{I} & \textbf{0} &\textbf{0}
\\
\textbf{0}&\mathbf{B}-\lambda \mathbf{I}&\mathbf{C}
\\
\textbf{0}&\textbf{0}&-\lambda\mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]\,.$$
This shows that the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{M}$ is indeed
$$\chi_\mathbf{M}(t)=t^{n_1+n_3}\,\chi_{\mathbf{B}}(t)\,,$$
where $\chi_\mathbf{X}$ indicates the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $\mathbf{X}$.