# Eigen vectors of a matrix formed by other matrix whose eigen vectors are known.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $B$ has eigenvalues $1, 2, 3$ and $C$ has eigenvalues $4, 5, 6$, and $D$ has eigenvalues $1, 8, 9$, what are the eigenvalues of the $6 x 6$ matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} B & C \\ 0 & D \end{bmatrix}$$

$'0'$ means zero $3 x 3$ matrix

So far I am only able to figure out that the trace of matrix $A$ is $30$ by adding eigen values of $B$ and $C$. Stuck after that can't use the determinant property as we don't know the other values of matrix $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I hope the problem now meets the standards issued.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207865/the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix This should answer your question

Comment: @Rishabh Thankyou very much.